# clang 4 build error on <functional> with c++1z

Tags: c++, archlinux, clang++, c++17

I just updated my arch linux system to the latest which includes gcc 7.1.1. Trying to build this:

```
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 1;
}
```

using the command

```
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++1z
```

results in the error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/functional:60:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/unordered_map:47:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/bits/hashtable.h:37:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/bits/node_handle.h:39:
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:1032:27: error: use of class template 'optional'
      requires template arguments
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                          ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:451:11: note: template is declared here
    class optional
          ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:1032:40: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
                                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/../../../../include/c++/7.1.1/optional:1032:41: error: cannot use arrow operator on a type
  template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
```

Is this an error on my part, arch linux, or clang?

Update: (forgot to add versions)

- gcc package version 7.1.1-2 (provides /usr/include/c++ dir)
- clang package version 4.0.0-3

Comment: Looks like clang just doesn't support deduction guides yet.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that's what was going on here (and forgot about that as a feature of c++17). Thanks!

Comment: Same error here. Did you find any workaround ? The only one I found was to switch to g++..

Comment: No workaround for clang. As Barry said; it's just not implemented yet. In my case it was only a buildbot issue since most of my work uses g++ anyhow but the clang test builds are still failing.

Comment: Ok. Let's wait then...

Answer (score 7):

Little late but I would like to sum it up.

This:

```
template <typename _Tp> optional(_Tp) -> optional<_Tp>;
```

is the example of deduction guides. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951697/what-are-template-deduction-guides-in-c17) you can find nice explanation of this language feature.

New version of libstdc++ uses it in its implementation when -std=c++17 or c++1z flag is in use.
Unfortunately Clang does not support this feature yet. [Clang C++1z status page](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17) reports it as available only on SVN.

You can find bug report for Arch Linux [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/index.php?do=details&task_id=54276).