# What are std::vector deduction guides in C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I read about deduction guides for `std::vector` from using [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/deduction_guides).

**Example:**

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   std::vector x{v.begin(), v.end()}; // uses explicit deduction guide
}
```

So, I have some questions about it:

- What are `std::vector` deduction guides in C++17?
- Why and when do we need vector deduction?
- Here, Is `x` a `std::vector<int>` or a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: `x` is probably a `std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>`.

Comment: Try to add value to x to see: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/640910c60c5735c1) so `std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>`.

Comment: Do you know what deduction guides are in general? If not, [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) could be useful.

Comment: @gsamaras: I mean that by testing `x.push_back(42);`, `x.push_back(v.begin());` and `x.push_back(v);` (correct) compilers (with correct library) would tell the error/valid cases (and moreover error case should probably give the correct type).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What are `std::vector` deduction guides in C++17?

An user-defined deduction guide allows users to decide how [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) deduces arguments for a template class from its constructor arguments. In this case, it seems that `std::vector` has an explicit guide that should make construction from an iterator pair more intuitive.

---

> Why and when do we need vector deduction?

We don't "need" it, but it is useful in generic code and in code that's very obvious *(i.e. code where explicitly specifying the template arguments is not beneficial to the reader)*.

---

> Is `x` a `vector<int>` or a `vector<vector<int>>`?

Here's a nice trick to figure this out quickly - write a template function declaration without a definition and attempt to call it. The compiler will print out the type of the passed arguments. Here's what g++ 8 prints out:

```
template <typename> 
void foo();

// ...

foo(x);
```

> error: no matching function for call to `foo(std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > ...`

As you can see from the error message, `x` is deduced to `std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>`.

---

> Why?

`std::vector`'s deduction guides [are available on cppreference.org](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/deduction_guides). The Standard seems to define an explicit deduction guide from an iterator pair:

[image]

The behavior encountered in g++ 8 seems to be correct regardless, as *(quoting [Rakete1111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3980929/rakete1111))*

> - overload resolution prefers the constructor with `std::initializer_list` with the braced initializer list
> - other constructors are considered only after all `std::initializer_list` constructors have been tried in [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#List-initialization)

`std:vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>` is therefore the correct result when using list-initialization.  [**live example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3SZWR0sR2q3ezyxn)

When constructing `x` with `std::vector x(v.begin(), v.end())`, `int` will be deduced instead. [**live example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IEvJjxyOTljYvwMd)

Comment: Your last point is only half true. Even with the missing deduction guide, the type will be `std:vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>` because overload resolution prefers the constructor with `std::initializer_list` with the braced initializer list.

Comment: @Rakete1111 That's not what the example on cppreference suggests - I don't know if the example is correct, but user-defined deduction guide have priority over automatic deduction guide in some cases, which could make the deduction correct here.

Comment: @Rakete1111 According to [Best viable function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function), "6) or, if not that, F1 is generated from a user-defined deduction-guide and F2 is not", I think it means the constructor with deduction guide is preferred in overload resolution.

Comment: @songyuanyao Yes I think so too, but isn't it the case that the other constructors are considered only *after* all `std::initializer_list` constructors have been tried in [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#List-initialization)? So, the iterator pair constructor is not even considered I think.

Comment: What @Rakete1111 said. `std:vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>` is the correct result.

Comment: And that cppreference example is now fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure I like that trick; you conveniently omitted the `&` in the error message (which signifies the value category). It doesn't matter in this case because you know what `x`'s type should roughly look like, but can be quite confusing if it can actually be a reference type.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'll admit I find it surprising that `std::initializer_list` is preferred over an explicit deduction guide like in the example, and I'm glad that the cppreference example was changed (as it was misleading). I've improved my answer.

Answer (score 7):

> Here, Is `x` a `std::vector<int>` or a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

The other answers here address your other questions, but I wanted to address this one a little more thoroughly. When we're doing class template argument deduction, we [synthesize a bunch of function templates](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1.1) from the constructors, and then some more from [deduction guides](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1.4) and perform overload resolution to determine the correct template parameters.

There are quite a few constructors to [`std::vector<T,A>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) , but most of them don't mention `T` which would make `T` a non-deduced context and thus not a viable option in this overload. If we pre-prune the set to only use the ones that could be viable:

```
template <class T> vector<T> __f(size_t, T const& );    // #2
template <class T> vector<T> __f(vector<T> const& );    // #5
template <class T> vector<T> __f(vector<T>&& );         // #6, NB this is an rvalue ref
template <class T> vector<T> __f(initializer_list<T> ); // #8
```

And then also this [deduction guide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/deduction_guides), which I'll also simplify by dropping the allocator:

```
template <class InputIt>
vector<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type> __f(InputIt, InputIt );
```

Those are our 5 candidates, and we're overloading as if by [dcl.init], a call via `__f({v.begin(), v.end()})`. Because this is list-initialization, we [start with the `initializer_list` candidates](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list#1.1) and, only if there aren't any, do we proceed to the other candidates. In this case, there is an `initializer_list` candidate that is viable (#8), so we select it without even considering any of the others. That candidate deduces `T` as `std::vector<int>::iterator`, so we then restart the process of overload resolution to select a constructor for `std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>` list-initialized with two iterators.

This is probably not the desired outcome - we probably wanted a `vector<int>`. The solution there is simple: use `()`s:

```
std::vector x(v.begin(), v.end()); // uses explicit deduction guide
```

Now, we're not doing list-initialization so the `initializer_list` candidate isn't a viable candidate. As a result, we deduce `vector<int>` through the deduction guide (the only viable candidate), and end up calling the iterator-pair constructor of it. This has the side benefit of actually making the comment correct.

---

This is one of the many places where initializing with `{}` does something wildly different than initializing with `()`. Some argue that `{}` is uniform initialization - which examples like this seem to counter. My rule of thumb: use `{}` when you specifically, consciously need the behavior that `{}` provides. `()` otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

> What are `std::vector` deduction guides in C++17?

[Class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) specifies: "In order to instantiate a class template, every template argument must be known, but not every template argument has to be specified."

And that's localized for `std:vector`, I mean a `std:vector` is just a class. Nothing special about it.

Here is the `std::vector` deducation guide from the ref:

```
template< class InputIt,
          class Alloc = std::allocator<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>
vector(InputIt, InputIt, Alloc = Alloc())
  -> vector<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type, Alloc>;
```

If you are unfamiliar with the syntax, please read [What are template deduction guides in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951697/what-are-template-deduction-guides-in-c17)

> Why and when do we need vector deduction?

You need guides when the deduction of the type from the arguments is not based on the type of one of those arguments.

> Is x a `vector<int>` or a `vector<vector<int>>`?

Neither!

It's an:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>
```

Forcing a simple compilation error (by assigning a number to `x` for example) will unveil its type):

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > >' and 'int')
```

---

PS:

> Why do we need that initialization, Alloc = Alloc() in that guide?

That's a *default argument*, which allows to pass in an allocator. The defaulting means you don't need two guides.

Comment: Why do we need that initialization, `Alloc = Alloc()` in that guide? Isn't `Alloc` just good enough to represent the type itself?

Comment: @DeanSeo It's a default argument.

Comment: @Barry Right. But what we need from a deduction guide is type, not arguments? The compiler already knows its _default_ type without *Alloc()* it seems?

Comment: @Dean ... because it's a default argument. This guide also handles the case where you pass in an allocator. The defaulting means you don't need two guides.

Comment: I agree with @Barry, answer updated (although I am not sure if I should do that). Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: @Barry Ah I see, just like a function template. I guess I am not used to the syntax of the deduction guide. Thanks. :)