# Why pair doesn't need types in initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, std-pair

I try this in Visual Studio c++ 2017, it works

```
auto a = pair(1.0, 2);
```

I think it should be

```
auto a = pair<double, int>(1.0, 2);
```

Why are the template not necessary here?

Comment: Do you mean `std::make_pair`? It already has them. 1.0 *is* a `double` and `2` *is* an `int`. The types are deduced from the arguments.

Comment: @WhozCraig I use pair. Can types be deduced for classes? I think it is for functions only.

Comment: See: [Class template argument deduction(since C++17) - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: Thanks to @NickyC for saving me the time of linking that. props! Now I see your question is less related to type deduction and more related to the context that deduction happens in. I glossed over your vs2017 reference. Nicky should post that as an answer with a brief description (unless there is a duplicate somewhere; I've not seen it if there is).

Comment: You don't need this ugly `<double, int>` any more. This is one of the  selling points of C++17.

Comment: @WhozCraig Posted an answer as you suggested. I hope I have written it well.

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature new to C++17, known as [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). In short, this feature allows you to omit template arguments of a class template and let the compiler deduce the arguments when you declare an object of a instance of a class template.

[`std::pair` has a deduction guide in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/deduction_guides) that looks like this:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
pair(T1, T2) -> pair<T1, T2>;
```

The expression `pair(1.0, 2)` is a function-style cast expression with no explicit template argument list, which is one of several triggers of class template argument deduction.

When class template argument deduction is triggered, the compiler looks up the compiler-generated and user-written deduction guides, and discovers the deduction guide mentioned above. This deduction guide tells the compiler to deduce `T1` as `double` and `T2` as `int` bases on the constructor arguments `(1.0, 2)`.

Also see:

- [Class template argument deduction(since C++17) - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)
- [deduction guides for std::pair - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/deduction_guides)
- [c++ - What are template deduction guides and when should we use them? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40951697/2486888)
- [cpp-docs/visual-cpp-language-conformance.md at master · MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/visual-cpp-language-conformance.md)