# C++ error use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to pass a function as parameter to class, but getting error as `use of class template requires template argument list`.

```
#include <iostream>

void f_global ()
{
    std::cout << "In function global\n";
}

template<typename F>
class A
{
public:
    F f1;
    A(const int var1, F fun1) : a(var1), f1(fun1) {}
    void f2();

private:
    int a;

};

void A::f2()
{
    std::cout << "in A::f2()\n";
}
int main()
{
    A obj(5,f_global);
    obj.f2();
}
```

I am trying to use auto template deduction feature while passing function from `obj` [What are template deduction guides and when should we use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951697/what-are-template-deduction-guides-and-when-should-we-use-them)

Comment: Which line triggers the error? Which compiler, version, and flags are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are simply missing the template parameter in the definition of `A::f2()`:

```cpp
template<typename F>
void A<F>::f2()
{
    std::cout << "in A::f2()\n";
}
```

When the member function definition is outside of the class definition, then the above syntax is necessary to provide proper template instantiation.