# Implementation of std::array

Tags: c++, c++17

I was looking at MSVC's implementation of std::array and saw this:

```
#if _HAS_CXX17
template <class _First, class... _Rest>
struct _Enforce_same {
    static_assert(conjunction_v<is_same<_First, _Rest>...>,
        "N4687 26.3.7.2 [array.cons]/2: "
        "Requires: (is_same_v<T, U> && ...) is true. Otherwise the program is ill-formed.");
    using type = _First;
};

template <class _First, class... _Rest>
array(_First, _Rest...)->array<typename _Enforce_same<_First, _Rest...>::type, 1 + sizeof...(_Rest)>;
#endif // _HAS_CXX17
```

How does that second thing work? It doesn't look like a class or a function, so what is it?

Comment: Deduction guide. It's for CTAD, i.e. class template argument deduction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951697/what-are-template-deduction-guides-and-when-should-we-use-them