# are there any predicate adaptors/buiders in std::ranges?

Tags: c++, c++20

I am experimenting composition with ranges & views, but I cannot find any way to express common patterns of predicates.

I have this container of key-value pairs

```
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> countries = {
        { 1, "Germany"},
        { 2, "UK"},
        { 3, "Spain"},
        { 4, "Sweden"}
    };
```

and I want to find the first occurrence where KEY '3' and *copy* its VALUE:

```
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    int key = 3;

    std::ranges::copy(
            (countries 
            | std::views::filter([key](auto const &p){ return p.first == key; })
            | std::views::take(1)
            | std::views::values
            ),
            std::back_inserter(result));
```

I often find myself writing simple predicates like "key_equals_to", "value_not_equals_to", over and over again. Which is noisy.

**Question 1:**
Is there any way to compose/express such *simple* predicates with the standard library,
without having to write such simple lambdas everywhere?
Or should I write a library, or set of common predicates *by myself*? Any good examples of such a library?

**Question 2:**
I wanted to use the adaptor `std::views::keys` to get the `pair::first` instead of the lambda, but that would hide the `pair::second` from the rest of the pipe.
Is there an alternative ranges/views way to achieve this in this example?

[here is the full code](https://godbolt.org/z/1hqxfxdde)

Answer (score 2):

There aren't predicates in the standard library. It is fairly normal to express those as lambdas.

If you really don't like writing lots of lambdas, something like the following would get you a long way:

```
namespace predicates {
    template<typename T, typename Proj = std::identity>
    struct equal_to {
        T needle;
        Proj proj = {};

        template<typename E>
        bool operator()(E&& elem) {
            return needle == std::invoke(proj, std::forward<E>(elem));
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    equal_to(T) -> equal_to<T>;
    template<typename T, typename Proj>
    equal_to(T, Proj) -> equal_to<T, Proj>;

    // ditto for !=, <, >, <=, >=
}

namespace projections {
    constexpr auto key_of = []<typename T>(T&& pair) {
        return std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(pair));
    };

    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto value_of = []<typename T>(T&& pair) {
        return std::get<1>(std::forward<T>(pair));
    };
}
```

With those few types, you get to have

```
        | std::views::filter(predicates::equal_to{ key, projections::key_of })
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/cTdsa4scP)

If you already have a dependancy on boost, that can be implemented more succinctly with [boost::hof::partial](https://boost-hof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/include/boost/hof/partial.html), [boost::hof::proj](https://boost-hof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/include/boost/hof/proj.html) and [BOOST_HOF_LIFT](https://boost-hof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/include/boost/hof/lift.html).

```
namespace projections {
    template<size_t I>
    constexpr auto element_of = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::get<I>);
    constexpr auto key_of = element_of<0>;
    constexpr auto value_of = element_of<1>;

    template <typename T, typename M>
    constexpr auto member_of(M T::*member) {
        return boost::hof::partial(BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::invoke))(member);
    }
}

namespace predicates {
    constexpr auto equal_to = boost::hof::partial(std::equal_to{});
    constexpr auto not_equal_to = boost::hof::partial(std::not_equal_to{});
    constexpr auto less = boost::hof::partial(std::less{});
    constexpr auto less_equal = boost::hof::partial(std::less_equal{});
    constexpr auto greater = boost::hof::partial(std::greater{});
    constexpr auto greater_equal = boost::hof::partial(std::greater_equal{});

    // defining some common projections
    template <typename K>
    constexpr auto key_equal(K&& key) {
        return boost::hof::proj(projections::key_of, equal_to(std::forward<K>(key)));
    }
}
```

Which gives you

```
        | std::views::filter(predicates::key_equal(key))
```

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/5E6x4Gf41)

Comment: I haven't seen this syntax before: `equal_to(T) -> equal_to<T>;`
What's it called? where can I read about this?

Comment: @GrimFandango It is called [user-defined deduction guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951697/what-are-template-deduction-guides-and-when-should-we-use-them).

Comment: Shouldn't functions like `std::views::filter` and `std::views::drop_while` also have a projection parameter?
`std::views::filter( Pred pred, Proj proj={} );`  and
`std::views::drop_while( Pred pred, Proj proj={} );` 
Should I overload `filter()` and `drop_while()`, instead of making composable predicates? 
e.g. in an **stdE** namespace: `stdE::views::filter( Pred pred, Proj proj={} );`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to compose/express such simple predicates with the
> standard library, without having to write such simple lambdas
> everywhere?

You can define a variable template that makes such a lambda, for example

```
template<std::size_t N>
inline constexpr auto project_element = [](auto fun, auto rhs) {
  return [=](auto&& tuple) -> decltype(auto) {
    return std::invoke(
      fun, std::get<N>(std::forward<decltype(tuple)>(tuple)), rhs);
  };
};
inline constexpr auto project_key   = project_element<0>;
inline constexpr auto project_value = project_element<1>;
```

Then specify the template parameter `N` and pass in `std::equal_to` as predicates with the specified key

```
std::ranges::copy(
            (countries 
            | std::views::filter(project_key(std::equal_to{}, key))
            | std::views::take(1)
            | std::views::values
            ),
            std::back_inserter(result));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bxbe513n5)

Comment: Thank you - the helper function is useful.
Shouldn't functions like `std::views::filter` and `std::views::drop_while` also have a projection parameter?
`std::views::filter( Pred pred, Proj proj={} );`  and
`std::views::drop_while( Pred pred, Proj proj={} );` 
Should I overload `filter()` and `drop_while()`, instead of making composable predicates? 
e.g. in an **stdE** namespace: `stdE::views::filter( Pred pred, Proj proj={} );`

Comment: @GrimFandango "*Shouldn't functions like `std::views::filter` and `std::views::drop_while` also have a projection parameter?*" No, They are range adapters rather than *constrained algorithms*, which do not accept projection parameters, as this does not make sense for most of them such as `views::take`.